# Enumeration of k-means clusters

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

```
sample=['he buy fish','he buy bread','the pizza is die'
,'the man buy pizza','mcdonald is there','there is a boy',
'who beat the man','burger and pizza']

fidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000, min_df=0.2, stop_words='english',use_idf=True)
vect=TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
x=vect.fit_transform(sample)
idf=vect.idf_

dist = 1 - cosine_similarity(x)
num_clusters = 3

km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
km.fit(x)
clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
print(clusters)
```

output:

```
[2 2 0 0 1 1 0 0]
```

K-means work perfectly on the data. However, the cluster number is generated randomly between 0 ,1 and 2 without follow a sequence.

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you are trying to achieve? What is the question here?

Comment: What sequence are you talking about ?

Comment: i want the output like 0 0 1 1 2 2 1 1 instead of random for further processing

Comment: I don't see how the name of the cluster can be important, but since you now have a list you can modify, what's the problem ?

Comment: Please **don't repost near-duplicate questions** [Python K-means clustering on document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886584/python-k-means-clustering-on-document). If you would spend more time on asking better questions, you would likely get better answers. Use the "edit" option to improve your questions.

Answer (score 0):

k-means by *design* is a randomized algorithm.

It begins with *random* centers. And by running it multiple times, you can get different solutions. Some may be better than others - that is good.

Because it is randomized, it is not defined which cluster is cluster #0, #1, etc. - they *may* be permuted.